# Handle system folders event in windows

Tags: c#, winapi, event-handling, filesystems

I am writing some C# code and I need to detect if a specific folder on my windows file system has been opened while the application is running. Is there any way to do it? WinAPI maybe?

Comment: Hmmm - FileWatcher class but that's only for changes ...

Comment: Define opened? A handle to a file within the directory? Browsed to using Windows Explorer?

Comment: @josheinstein: Actually, I have not files inside. I only need to handle an event or message when the directory is opened from the windows explorer to look at the content.

Comment: Can you describe your scenario a bit more? Why do you need to know when the user is viewing your directory via Explorer? Would an ExplorerBrowser be a better design choice for your application?

Comment: @raymond: I need to do that because my app needs to see which folders are being opened by the users. I want to create some security stuff here. The explorer browser is the best choice for my users, because everybody knows how to use it.

Comment: You're not going to get a perfect answer, because users can open folders from other places, like the File.Open dialog, or anybody who uses an ExplorerBrowser control. Perhaps you can design your program some other way to get the security you want. For example, you can set the ACLs on the directory so users cannot write to it.

Comment: What's wrong with hosting an ExplorerBrowser control in your app? Users will still be using a control they are familiar with, and you control what they are looking at.

Comment: If you're trying to implement security by hacking into Explorer (the only way to do this is by a Shell Extension), you're in trouble. To put it another way: What are you trying to implement? You'll have to be more specific than "security stuff".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three API things I think you should check out:

FindFirstChangeNotification() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx
That gives you a handle you can wait on and use to find changes to a file in a particular file, directory, or tree of directories.  It won't tell you when a directory is browsed, but it will tell you when a file is saved, renamed, and so on and so forth.

SetWindowsHookEx() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
You can set that up to give you a callback when any number of events occur - in fact I'm pretty positive that you CAN get this callback when a directory is opened, but it will probably be inordinately difficult because you'll be intercepting messages to explorer's window.  So you'll be rebooting during debugging.

Windows Shells http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776778%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
If that wasn't painful enough, you can try writing a shell program.

If you're trying to write a rootkit, I suppose you don't want me to spoil the details for you.  If you're NOT trying to write a rootkit, I suggest you look it up - carefully.  There are open source rootkits, and they all basically have to monitor file access this way to hide from the user / OS.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the Windows Shell Extensions.  You can use Shell Namespace Extensions to make a "virtual" folder that isn't there (or hides a real one), like the GAC (C:\Windows\assembly)

[Here are several examples of Shell Extension coding in .Net 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx).

A [Column Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144067%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would let you know when a folder is "Opened", and even let you provide extra data for each of the files (new details columns).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **FileSystemWatcher** class.

Comment: As bryanmac told us, Unfortunately the FileSystemWatcher only works for changes (Deleted, Changed, Renamed, Created...)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that I can think of, that may be useful to you, is using the static Directory class.  It provides methods to determine the last time a file or directory was accessed.  You could setup a BackgroundWorker to monitor if the directory was accessed during a specified interval. Keep track of the start and end of the interval by using DateTime, and if the last access time falls between those, then  you can use the BackgroundWorker's ProgressChanged event to notify the application.

```
 BackgroundWorker folderWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
 folderWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
 folderWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
 folderWorker.DoWork += FolderWorker_DoWork;
 folderWorker.ProgressChanged += FolderWorker_ProgressChanged;

 folderWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

 void FolderWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
      BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

      while(!worker.CancellationPending)
      {
           DateTime lastAccess = Directory.GetLastAccessTime(DIRECTORY_PATH);

           //Check to see if lastAccess falls between the last time the loop started
           //and came to end.
           if(/*your check*/)
           {
                object state;  //Modify this if you need to send back data.
                worker.ReportProgress(0, state);
           }
      }
 }

 void FolderWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      //Take action here from the worker.ReportProgress being invoked.
 }
```

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but i tried that and the LastAccessTime does not change when I simply open a folder. It does not work for me.

Comment: LastAccessTime() actually returns the last time the OS recorded a modification to the folder or the contents of it. All I believe you'll be able to do is to watch for changes to the folder with the FileSystemWatcher then get the last access time.

Comment: Thanks @Dubs. But I only need to handle an event when the folder is being opened from the windows explorer. There are not changes in the folder in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the FileSystemInfo's LastAccessProperty. The problem though is that it can be cached.

FileSystemInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975xhcs9.aspx

LastAccessTime Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstimeutc.aspx

As noted that this can be pre-cached.

"The value of the LastAccessTimeUtc property is pre-cached if the current instance of the FileSystemInfo object was returned from any of the following DirectoryInfo methods:

GetDirectories

GetFiles

GetFileSystemInfos

EnumerateDirectories

EnumerateFiles

EnumerateFileSystemInfos

To get the latest value, call the Refresh method."

Therefore call the Refresh method but it still might not be up to date due to Windows caching the value. (This is according to msdn doc "FileSystemInfo.Refresh takes a snapshot of the file from the current file system. Refresh cannot correct the underlying file system even if the file system returns incorrect or outdated information. This can happen on platforms such as Windows 98." - link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.refresh.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I think the only way you can reliably achieve this is by monitoring the currently running processes and watch closely for new Explorer.exe instances and/or new Explorer.exe spawned threads (the "Run every window on a separate process" setting gets in the way here).

I admit I don't have a clue about how to code this, but that's what I would look for.

Comment: You have many other ways of monitoring the file system programmatically (FileSystemWatcher, and Directory along with BackgroundWorker, manipulate through autorun files that run automatically when the folder is accessed through Windows Explorer, etc...).