# Invoking a method when Windows Explorer opens a given folder

Tags: c#, events, directory, windows-explorer

I want to execute some C# method when a user opens a folder in Windows Explorer.

How to do such a thing?

Comment: Windows Service that is auto started. Keep track using a timer over all currently executing processes and look for iexplorer.exe process with title containing the desired folder.

Comment: Just because the answer is likely "no" it doesn't mean that the question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical.

Comment: Maybe these will help you: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7479583/290343), [2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/ITCG/thread/ae676f12-fff7-4efe-b438-e12ac5f1ff4b)

Comment: May be try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118452/how-to-identify-whether-folder-is-opened and implement a funtion within this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about this but this is what I would do/try,

have a C# program which starts up on logon [Open C# application on log on](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474092/Run-Csharp-application-on-Windows-startup-Windows) or just have your program running in some way and use [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you can make use of LastAccess notify filter and have your C# code get executed .

```
    // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = "folder path";

     /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
       the renaming of files or directories. */
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess;

    // add event handler
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That doesn't tell you if the folder was opened by Windows Explorer or just accessed by some arbitary process.